# how to know in which folder my file is

Tags: folder, item, api

How can i Know, using my item metadatas, the folder it is stored in? For example, I do this Get Request :

```
https://sharepoint.com/sites/SPSample/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items(2)/fieldvaluesastext
```

Do you know any fields in the result which can lead me to the previous folders? Except the "FileRef'

Thanks by advance,

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 properties other than 'FileRef'

FileDirRef - this will give you "/sites/mysc/Shared Documents/MyFolder"

ParentUniqueId - this will give you unique id of Folder - {GUID of folder}

You can use above 2 properties to call other REST API to determine folder name if you want to get any properties of folder.